# Can we generate logDNA alerts only based on the "presence" or "absence" of specified number of lines?

Tags: logdna

I have the following logs:

1. Taking a pg_dump
2. pg_dump successful
3. logging into cloud
4. logged in successfully
5. Uploading the backup
6. Upload successful

I want to generate a logDNA alert if line 1 AND line 6 do not appear every one hour.
(not worried about the rest of the lines)

I am aware that I can generate alerts if a specified number of alerts do not show up within some time interval. But wanted to understand can I generate it when a string/regex is missing!

Answer (score 1):

Got it!!
We can add in "query strings in the view" and then alert based on the number of lines...
In my case, I filter line 1 AND line 6 and say alert if fewer than 2 lines appear in an hour.